# Editing Solidwork's system options in C#

Tags: c#, solidworks

I am trying to edit a couple of settings in SolidWork's options menu through a C# program I wrote. The code is below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using SldWorks;
using SwConst;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  SldWorks.SldWorks swApp;
  swApp = new SldWorks.SldWorks();

  swApp.SetUserPreferenceToggle((int)swUserPreferenceToggle_e.swSingleCommandPerPick, true); /// Single command per pick
  swApp.SetUserPreferenceToggle((int)swUserPreferenceToggle_e.swEditMacroAfterRecord, true); /// Automatically edit macro after recording
  swApp.SetUserPreferenceToggle((int)swUserPreferenceToggle_e.swUserEnableFreezeBar, true);  /// Enable Freeze bar

  Console.WriteLine("Settings applied");
}
```

The intended purpose of this program is to toggle those three options (checkboxes) to true. So far this does not work at all. The options still stay the same even after I run the program. Am I missing anything or is my code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for example, mouse speed):

//View rotation - Mouse speed
bool boolstatus = swApp.SetUserPreferenceIntegerValue((int)swUserPreferenceIntegerValue_e.swViewRotationMouseSpeed, 56);

Thanks to Solidworks API:
http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/api/sldworksapi/Get_and_Set_User_Preferences_Example_CSharp.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to get the COM object while SolidWorks is running.

```
Try
{
    SldWorks swApp = (SldWorks)Marshal.GetActiveObject("SldWorks.Application");
    swApp.SetUserPreferenceToggle((int)swUserPreferenceToggle_e.swSingleCommandPerPick, true); /// Single command per pick
    swApp.SetUserPreferenceToggle((int)swUserPreferenceToggle_e.swEditMacroAfterRecord, true); /// Automatically edit macro after recording
    swApp.SetUserPreferenceToggle((int)swUserPreferenceToggle_e.swUserEnableFreezeBar, true);  /// Enable Freeze bar



    Console.WriteLine("Settings applied");
}
catch()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to get SolidWorks");
}
```